Range of values of θ that satisy these values.
The question:The value of θ for which $$x+y(\sin θ)=1, x(\sin θ)+4y=2$$ satisfy $$x>=\frac{4}{5}, y>=\frac{1}{3}$$
Note here θ must belong from $$(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$$
This is a question I was asked on a mock test. I skipped the question due to time constraint, but I'm still unable to solve it.
My first thought was to simply put in the limiting values of x and y in the equation.
This would give us $$\frac{4}{5}+\frac{sinθ}{3}=1,$$ which means $$\sin θ = \frac{3}{5}$$ and that is for 37°. Similarly putting it into the second variable gives $$\sin θ=\frac{5}{6}.$$ But the answer was in terms of a range of values that θ can take.
I also thougth of finding out the determinant of the linear equations but that didn't help either.
It was given in a matrices and determinants test, so hopefully if anyone could get a solution using matrices and determinants it would be of great help.

The system of equations can be rewritten as $$\begin{pmatrix}
1& \sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & 4 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Applying Cramer's Rule, we have $$x=\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}
1& \sin(\theta)\\
2 & 4 
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1& \sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & 4 
\end{vmatrix}}=\dfrac{4-2\sin(\theta)}{4-\sin^2(\theta)}=2\dfrac{2-\sin(\theta)}{4-\sin^2(\theta)}=\dfrac{2}{2+\sin(\theta)}$$ $$y=\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}
1& 1\\
\sin(\theta) & 2 
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1& \sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & 4 
\end{vmatrix}}=\dfrac{2-\sin(\theta)}{4-\sin^2(\theta)}=\dfrac{1}{2+\sin(\theta)}$$
As $\sin(\theta)\in [-1,1]$ we always have $y\geq \dfrac{1}{3}$.
In order to have $x\geq \dfrac{4}{5}$, we need $$\dfrac{2}{2+\sin(\theta)}\geq\dfrac{4}{5}\iff 10\geq 8+4\sin(\theta)\iff \sin(\theta)\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$$
As $\theta\in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$, this condition is equivalent to $\theta\in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)$.
